# Subtables in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am working on a database that has one main table with the entry rows having an individual table for calculations.

So I have about 9 tables that have calculations /values in that are associated with an individual indicator field entry in my main table. I would like to link the calculation tables to the individual entry.

The subdatasheet allows me to do this. However, it populates all the entries with the same table which I do not want as one calculation table is only associated to one entry.

I can’t create one table for all calculations as they have different types of data and are calculated differently so I can’t link with regards to relationships.

The only solution I can think of is by populating a new field called “results calculations” and populate it with the title of the calculation table associated to the individual entry.

Is there another way I would love all the data to be as accessible in one table as simplified as possible.
(I am new to MS Access so any advice will be appreciated.)

[The result of using subdatasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhlls.png)

[What I need to link to each indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScFOM.png)

Comment: Question is too broad and responses would be opinion-based and is therefore not really appropriate for SO. Might want to post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I may not be understanding correctly as always it helps to show us what you have and what you want.  Anyways if you have one main table hooked up to 9 tables with 1tomany relationships.  Create a subform for each!!!! of the 9 calculations tables.  Then figure out how to display 9 subforms on one form.  Fit em all?  add a tab control and put them in tabs?.  My favorite is to make all the subforms the same size, then set their visibility to false, then stack them on top of each other.  Then I throw in some radio buttons or some such to turn the subform I want to see visible.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have attached two images I hope will be helpful in understanding my question. The calculation tables are needed to extract values and to create graphs which need to be updated every 6 months. It is impossible for me to create a unified table with all the calculations in one as they are all different.

Comment: It looks like you should have just one calculations table with a relationship to your main table (Key ID?).  The relationship will define what records to show from your calculations table.

Comment: Having just one calculation table will only allow me to provide characters of the calculation tables as fields for example - units of measure, formula, levels of measure etc. Which is not required, and I would still need to find a way to link the individual calculation tables to the one calculations table. From all the research I've been doing it seems unlikely that I can connect them individually and without forming a relationship between the tables.